# Swift - Guard-let vs if-let

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am having some issues getting the following code to work, any ideas why it doesn't work?

```
guard let parsedData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments),
    let parsedDict = parsedData as? [String:Any],
    let stop = parsedDict["Stop"] as? [String:Any],
    let name = stop["Name"] as? String,
    let latitude = stop["Latitude"] as? String,
    let longitude = stop["Longitude"] as? String else
    {
        print("Something Went Wrong")
        return
    }

    nameArray.append(name)
    latArray.append(latitude)
    longArray.append(longitude)
```

However, the following code does work:

```
if let parsedData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:Any]
{
    if let stop = parsedData?["Stop"] as? [String:Any]
    {
        if let latitude = stop["Latitude"] as? String, let longitude = stop["Longitude"] as? String, let name = stop["Name"] as? String
        {
            nameArray.append(name)
            latArray.append(latitude)
            longArray.append(longitude)
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

After reviewing the code, the issue seems to stem from this line:

```
guard let stop = parsedDict["Stop"] as? [String:Any] else
{
    print("Something went wrong")
    return
}
```

When running this I receive "Something went wrong" in the console, however when running

```
if let stop = parsedData?["Stop"] as? [String:Any]
{
    print(stop)
}
```

I get a valid print of stop.

Comment: When I run the code I get "Something Went Wrong" in the console. I made an edit

Comment: "After reviewing the code, the issue seems to stem from this line: `guard let stop = innerParsedDict["Stop"] as? [String:Any] else`" But where _is_ that line? None of the code you showed contains anything called `innerParsedDict`!

Comment: sorry *parsedDict*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Running your guard example myself in a playground is successful for me. I would recommend breaking up your guard into multiple logical sections. For example to help you track down your error you could change it to:

```
//Note: You should not force unwrap data here

guard let parsedData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) else{
    print("Serialization error"); return
}

guard
    let parsedDict = parsedData as? [String:Any],
    let stop = parsedDict["Stop"] as? [String:Any] else {

        print("Error casting to dictionary"); return
}

guard
    let name = stop["Name"] as? String,
    let latitude = stop["Latitude"] as? String,
    let longitude = stop["Longitude"] as? String else {

    print("Error casting dictionary values"); return
}

//Everything is ok here
```

Comment: I agree with what you said about breaking up the guard statement, however I still have an issue. I edited the question with details on where the issue occurs

Comment: The issue is that your two lines that you describe in the edit are not the same so it will not help you find your mistake. You are comparing apples to oranges...